# Embedding of the line as a bounded subset of plane

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can i embed R as a bounded subset of the plane? Or how can i prove that such an embedding exists?
R is not bounded and also is metric and i can not find such embeding,if it exist does it preserve the metric?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ - a bounded subset of the plane. But no such map can preserve the metric - for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Stefan What about defining a new metric on the embedded line by using arc-length? Curling it enough might do the job ;-)

Comment: @Pedro Sure, given any injection, we can always carry over the metric. But I think OP wants to equip the image in the plane with the restriction of the euclidean metric.

Comment: @Stefan Of course, but I found it amazing that you can do it preserving lengths. Thanks!